# Transform individual values without overwriting themselves

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I would like to create css hooks for individual transform values that doesn't overwrite themselves, so this:

```
$(selector).css('rotateY',-20);
$(selector).css('rotateX',80);
```

Would become this (applying the correct prefix):

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-20deg) rotateY(80deg);
```

I've found transform csshooks, but they don't do exactly what i want: 
https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js
Although these css hooks seem to do a good crossbrowser job (even IE), they do not allow individual transformations whithout having to write the entire transform (with the old values).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track... Using [`cssHooks`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) is the common way to extend/override how jQuery should handle getting and setting css properties.

Here is a really, really… simple example of how this could be done:

```
function createTransformHook(transformFunction, unitless) {
  var transformProperty = 'transform', transformList

  $.cssHooks[transformFunction] = {
    get: function(elem) {
      return ($.data(elem, transformProperty) || {})[transformFunction]
    },
    set: function(elem, value) {
      transformList = $.data(elem, transformProperty) || {}
      transformList[transformFunction] = value
      $.data(elem, transformProperty, transformList)
      $.style(elem, transformProperty, $.map(transformList, function(value, key) {
        return key + '(' + value + ')'
      }).join(' '))
    }
  }

  $.fx.step[transformFunction] = function(fx) {
    $.cssHooks[transformFunction].set(fx.elem, fx.now + fx.unit)
  }

  if (unitless) {
    $.cssNumber[transformFunction] = true
  }
}
```

This function takes the [`transform-function`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) and an optional second argument, to declare it as a unitless property (Don't automatically add `'px'`). It also adds the property to the global `jQuery.fx.step` object, that makes it possible to animate the value with jQuerys default animate function.

You can use it as follows:

```
createTransformHook('translateX')
createTransformHook('translateY')
createTransformHook('rotateX', true)
createTransformHook('rotateY', true)
createTransformHook('rotate', true)
createTransformHook('scaleX', true)
createTransformHook('scaleY', true)
createTransformHook('scale', true)
// etc...
```

...then just write your transforms like any other css property:

```
$(selector).css({
  translateX: '-50%',
  translateY: '-50%',
  rotate: '45deg'
})
```

## https://fiddle.jshell.net/88w1b2qq/

*As said, it's really simple and naive, just an example...*

---

#### `$.cssHooks[transformFunction]`

> Hook directly into jQuery to override how particular CSS properties are retrieved or set, normalize CSS property naming, or create custom properties.

#### `$.fx.step[transformFunction]`

> A css hook can also hook into jQuery's animation mechanism by adding a property to the jQuery.fx.step object

#### `$.cssNumber[transformFunction]`

> An object containing all CSS properties that may be used without a unit. The .css() method uses this object to see if it may append px to unitless values

### Dive deeper

- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js (start here!)
- https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks
- https://github.com/zachstronaut/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale/
- https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/blob/a2a238968347199842dd7e2d552741d5a63c90b9/jquery.isotope.js
- http://awardwinningfjords.com/2011/05/06/trigger-css3-animations-with-jquery.html
- http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/01/25/how-animate-really-works-in-jquery-simple-animation-case-discussed.html